# What OOP design pattern would work best for an overseeing class connecting related objects enforced at compile-time?

Tags: object-oriented, c++, object-oriented-design, c++11

## The Problem

I would like to create a managing "overseer" class that connects several related object groups together where any particular group is able to be easily swapped for another using C++11 syntax.

A secondary goal of finding a good approach to code structure is to make the underlying code run quickly (since it will be used for conducting many simulations).

For context, this particular problem is something I have encountered in several other programming languages, but have not been able to find a great solution for in a compiled language.

## Minimal Example

### Classes

1. Arcade
2. ArcadeGame
3. ArcadeScreen
4. ArcadeMove
5. ArcadePlayer

### Problem Definition

1. Suppose there exists an `Arcade` which sets up an `ArcadeGame`every day for tournaments.
2. Each `ArcadeGame` displays an `ArcadeScreen` as its output and accepts an `ArcadeMove` as its input.
3. Each `ArcadeMove` and `ArcadeScreen` is unique to the `ArcadeGame` (e.g.: a `GalaxySpacewarGame` has different attributes in its `ArcadeMove` than a `CombatFighterGame`).
4. An `ArcadePlayer` for any particular game must be able to take the `ArcadeScreen` as input and output a valid `ArcadeMove` for that game.
5. The role of `Arcade` is to setup the `ArcadeGame`, ensure the `ArcadePlayer` is one that can actually play the game, and monitor the in-progress game to record the score of the player to a scoreboard.

### Pseudocode of the listed classes

The following classes share these functions:

```
ArcadeGame
   Restart()
   ArcadeScreen GetScreen()
   InputMove(ArcadeMove a)
   int GetScore()
   bool IsOver()

ArcadePlayer
   ArcadeMove GetInput(ArcadeScreen a)

Arcade
   Arcade(ArcadeGame g) // constructor
   int PlayTournamentGame(ArcadePlayer p):
      g.Restart()
      while NOT activeTournamentGame.IsOver():
         ArcadeMove m = p.GetInput(g.GetScreen())
         g.InputMove(m)
      return g.GetScore()
```

The classes will then be used like so:

```
GalaxySpacewarGame spaceGame = new GalaxySpacewarGame(someConfigParams1);
GalaxySpacewarPlayer john = new GalaxySpacewarPlayer(someConfigParams2);
Arcade someArcade = new Arcade(spaceGame)
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++):
   std::cout << PlayTournamentGame(john) << std::endl;
```

## Attempted Approaches

- I was taking a look at [type erasure](http://davekilian.com/cpp-type-erasure.html) specifically as a way of ensuring the `Arcade` class does would not require knowledge of the `ArcadeScreen`s for any of its games but do not see an easy way to enforce compile-time validation to ensure the `ArcadePlayer` is able to play that specific game. I am also unfamiliar with this specific design approach and would like to ask for a second opinion on whether it applies in this case.
- I have also taken a look at the visitor and double dispatch patterns, but it does not look like any of those alone would be useful for this kind of architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're describing the [mediator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) pattern.

I'm not sure about your compile-time validation requirement. If you have an `ArcadeGame` class that takes an `ArcadePlayer`, I'm not sure access control can be enforced at compile-time without a custom preprocessor step or just encoding the rules in your build process.  For example, if you were using Makefiles, you'd have an `asteroids` target that spec'd which `ArcadePlayer`(s) could play it.

Comment: In the case of a mediator for this design pattern, would both `ArcadePlayer` and `ArcadeGame` need to cast the passed `ArcadeScreen` and `ArcadeMove` to a narrower class respectively? Is there any need to pass typing information between the two classes or to the mediator?

Thank you for introducing me to the pattern, it was something I heard about before but did not look further into.

Comment: They shouldn't need to do any casting. `ArcadeScreen` should be an interface/abstract base class that defines all the operations you would need.  If you find that you need to cast that class to something more specific, you should review your design.

It's also possible that the Mediator pattern isn't appropriate for your actual use case.